# Conversation & Retrieve and Rank

Tags: json, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, retrieve-and-rank

After calling retrieve and rank in conversation using context variable, for example, I go to the JSON of the conversation and create a variable: ("call_retrieve_and_rank": true) On my server (python) When this variable is true, it searches the retrieve and Rank How to return to the last conversation node that was happening before the user asked something of Retrieve and Rank?

Answer (score 1):

After you create your node with the context variable `("call_retrieve_and_rank": true)`, add other node with one condition, or `true` condition and add the context variable with the value `false`:

`("call_retrieve_and_rank": false)`

And enter an answer with the *same* question that was happening before the user asked something of Retrieve and Rank

After user obtain the response for Retrieve and Rank, if him say something, this flow will appear to user and will show the message what you inserted in the node, and with this `context` variable set to `false`, Retrieve and rank will not call again.